# Transition between images in vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, image, vue.js, transition

I want to create a smooth transition between 2 images with a legend. The images come from an object-array of images.

Because works only on single tags and components, I've created a component to define the image+legend.

```
<transition>
    <home-image :slide="slide" :key="slide"></home-image>
</transition>
```

The classes I define are like this

```
.v-enter-active,
.v-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

.v-leave,
.v-enter-to {
    opacity: 1;
}

.v-enter,
.v-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

The new image is returned by a method

```
updateSlide() {
    this.slide = this.entries[ Math.floor( Math.random() * this.entries.length ) ];
}
```

where entries is my array defined in data

this.slide is updated in regular intervals, every 10seconds like this, which is defined in the created() section

```
this.updateSlide();
this.uSlide = setInterval( this.updateSlide, 10000);
```

The code works, in the sense that a new image is loaded in this.slide every 10 seconds. However, the transitions work only "half-way".

There is no transition fading out: the "old image" disappears and makes way for the new image fading in.

However, what I'd like is a smooth transition from one to the other.

I've tried more than a couple of ideas including using mode="out-in" and "in-out" but nothing works as I want.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Nothing here indicates that the fade out would just disappear, there must be some other cause.  You should probably give your transition a name though and change your class names accordingly.  See the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components) for an example.

Comment: Naming the transition doesn't change the issue. I first worked with names, but since according to the doc I can avoid a name, I removed it (it's the only transition I'm using)

Comment: No, I didn't think it would, it was only a general recommendation for clarity.  The primary statement was "nothing here indicates that the fade out would just disappear, there must be some other cause".  Reproducing the code shown on this page will create a transition that works in both directions

Comment: Could you put up a snippet which demonstrates the problem. It seems likely that the outgoing image is being immediately overwritten by the incoming one but a snippet would make this easier to verify..

Answer (score 0):

Found out position in v-enter and v-leave had to be set.

Code is now:

```
.v-leave,
.v-enter-to {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
}

.v-enter,
.v-leave-to {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is you want two elements to occupy the same space at the same time (one fading out, one fading in). One way of doing it is having one in the document flow and the other one out (using `position: absolute`). Another solution is to use `display:grid` on the parent and `grid-area: 1/1;` on the children. The second technique has the advantage that all children are in flow, so if one is taller, that one will set the size, regardless of being first or second. Using `position` only the element in document flow sets parent position.

Comment: Also note vue transitions have a [built-in "solution"](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes) for this. You can place `mode="out-in"` on the transition and the `enter` transition will wait for the `leave-to` to finish (and its element to be removed from DOM) before it runs. However, in your case, this means the first element will fade to whatever the background of your page is and when that fading is done, the new one will fade in. Overlapping them (with either `position` or `display:grid`) allows you to fade an element onto the previous one.

Comment: And, one more note: you don't (and shouldn't) need to fade the elements out. Why? Because, if you do, during the transitions both the elements are transparent (so the user gets to see the background). Technically, fading from one element to another is achievable by displaying the new element on top of the old one, fading the new one from `0` to `1` opacity and removing the old one, without ever changing the old one's opacity.

Comment: I've tried mode="out-in". It's not satisfactory as it will first fade one image before fading in the new one. However, I wanted them to work simultaneously. Position does the trick.